# How to check if ever purchased some in-app features

Tags: android, google-play, in-app

If I publish only free version to Google Play and if user want to unlock some features or remove the ads via in-app purchase, how to program to check if they ever purchased that. Is there any Google Play API to get that data?

And if they reinstall that free version on another devices, how to realise to unlock the feature also by not storing any purchase logs on my own server.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Billing API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html). You should try to search, then ask a question.